# Search for specific text and show text with img

Tags: jquery, html, search, parent, show

I am making a roster, each athlete has their own html:

```
    <div class="athlete"><a href="athlete.html">
        <div class="name"><p>Athlete Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="image"><img src="_images/athletes/athlete_pic.jpg">
        </div></a>
    </div>
```

where the `<a>` tag points to a specific athlete-profile html file. The `<p>` (showing their name) and `<img>` (showing an image of them) are unique to each athlete. After having been given a list of a lot of athletes I am using a search function to make it easier on the user to find a specific athlete. Another post helped me find this code for the search:

```
  jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) { 
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
  };
  jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) { 
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0; 
  };

    $('#inpSearch').on('keyup',function(){
        $('#wrapper div').not("#search-block").hide();
        var val = this.value;
        val = val.split(" ");
        var contains="";
        for(var i = 0; i < val.length;i++){
            contains.length >0?contains+=",div":"";
            contains+=":contains('"+val[i]+"')";
        }
        $('#wrapper div'+ contains).show();
});
```

Which works great, but the search results only `.show()` the athlete's name i.e. `<p>` tag. How could I edit this code to make the search result `.show()` the entire block of html for the athlete(s) whose name matches the search?

Comment: You should load the content of athlete.html using ajax.

Comment: Well the idea is that a search for Smith returns all the athletes with Smith in their name as an img of their face and their name above it. Then you can click this to go to that athlete page

Comment: There is a grid of images of am the athletes with their name above the image. The search function will reduce the amount in the grid to those that fill the criteria. There are instances were multiple athletes will be returned for certain search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps someone else in future. The answer is to include the parent class in the selectors. For this example, to show the entire html block that wraps around the html:

```
$('#wrapper div.athlete')
```